# My local server meets magento requirements, but install operation hangs on the last step...?

Tags: magento, installation

I took a test with [magento-check.php](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento/) file and it said that:

> "Congratulations! Your server meets
>   the requirements for Magento."

But installation procedure simply hangs on the last step and throws execution_time exceeded error, despite the fact, that I already rised it up to 3000 secs.

Any place where I can look for the problem?

**UPDATE**:

The error is:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of
>   3000 seconds exceeded in
>   /magento/www/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php
>   on line 591

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Updated with the actual error.

Comment: Looking at the error message my guess would be, that you used an invalid hostname for the install, but this shouldn't ever result in a maximum execution time issue (can't even imagine any hardware needing 50+ minutes for a simple Magento installation).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is failing when testing for mod_rewrite. There is an option to disable that test in the installation. If installation then succeeds then you'll need to work on getting mod_rewrite to work or else you won't have SEO friendly URLs.

Comment: I check "Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step" and do not check "Use Web Server (Apache) Rewrites", but it doesn't help :|

Answer (score 1):

Setup a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) under your hosts file and use it during installation. Up the [maximum execution time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in PHP, and if all else fails after that try installing via the [Command Line Interface](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/international_wikis/french/installer_magento_avec_un_acces_shell).

Answer (score 0):

Place a file in your doc root with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, call it `mycheck.php` and load it up. Read for yourself the php options and settings and make sure that the execution time is not over-written by server defaults. (This should be clear from the two column output of `phpinfo()`.